# How do I add captions to inserted figures

Tags: support, images

Some of my MO answers  have  figures in them.   How  do   I add   captions  and tags to them?

Comment: How do you make those figures? If it's an external image file, just add the caption there.

Comment: I wrote   a caption but it did not come out right. See  the 6th picture (from ttop to bottom) in this answer https://mathoverflow.net/questions/328497/circle-inscribed-between-two-curves/328506#328506

Comment: Those captions are *not* captions that appear below your figure. Those are meant as alternative text for screen readers or so.

Comment: This rather old feature request is a bit related: [Add Image Captions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/142750). The answer posted there basically explains that MarkDown has no predefined way to do that.

Comment: What do you mean by "tags" exactly?

Answer (score 6):

One way to approximate a figure caption is to add this immediately
after your image:

```
<br />
&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; 
<sup>
Figure caption here.
</sup>
<br />
```

The **br** breaks to a new line. The **&nbsp**'s tab in horizontally.
The **sup**'s make the tex smaller (superscript). For example:

---

[image]

          

<sup>Random vectors in a disk: [MSE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3012327/237).</sup>

---